# Are two-edge connectivity and Strongly connected components the same concept?

Tags: algorithm, graph, connected-components

I was just wondering if the two-edge connectivity and strongly connected components are the same concept. For some reason I can relate the two but still confused because they have different names.

Answer (score 0):

The concepts are related, but strongly directed components are defined for *directed* graphs only, while 2-edge connectivity is defined for undirected graphs.

According to Robbins' theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins%27_theorem), the 2-edge connected graphs are exactly the graphs that can have their edges oriented to create a strongly connected directed graphs (i.e., a directed graph that consists of a single strongly connected component).